# Organizing Files in Command Prompt? Windows 8

Tags: windows, command, prompt

I am looking to figure out how I can go about organizing certain files by name using the command prompt?

Do I use the sort function?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Are you asking for renaming or moving files?

Comment: For example: `rename test.txt hope.txt`

Comment: Sorry, I'm asking about moving files

Comment: `move c:\windows\temp\*.* c:\temp` this command moves every file in c:\windows\temp\ to c:\temp.